# Algorithm to migrate database records

Tags: data-migration

I need to migrate 200'000 records from one database (oracle) to another (SQL Server). I will manage the migration with SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) and I already created the package.

The records refer to documents in the database (with a HBLOB field). They require quite some time to be migrated, therefore I introduced variables in SSIS in order to migrate each time only a subset of records by using a query that takes the variables as bundaries. In this way I can start move some historic records before the going live date.

At the beginning I though to move by IDs, as example taking the first block of 1'000 then the second block and so on. But this is not possible since some documents (being in production system) can still be changed, therefore they cannot be moved yet.

Here the contrainsts:

```
If "Status" is closed   -> the document can be safely taken 
                           (other statuses are draft, pending).
If "CreatedDate" < 2010 -> the document can be moved without taking care of status.
```

1. At first instance, I can move all "old" documents (created before 2010).
2. I would move all documents in status "closed".
3. The day of go live, I will then migrate all the remaining records.

However with this pattern it is not easy to keep track of the moved documents (at point [2]) since other documents can go into status closed in the meantime.

Can anyone suggest a better procedure to move these records without the risk of taking duplicates or missing any data?

Comment: A closed document can be created before 2010, isn't it? So you cannot be sure you're moving the same doc twice. Am I wrong?

Comment: Do you track the closed/completed date for each document?

Comment: @Francesco: I would move all documents created before 2010 first and then the closed one, but whose date is after the 2010 threshold. In this way I will avoid "old" duplicates.

Comment: @Dan: Each document has a status, createDate, LastUpdateDate. Maybe I could use LastUpdateDate field to set a threshold. Like: "take all records whose status is closed and LastUpdateDate < day X", then afterwards I can take all records in status closed and whose LastUpdateDate is before the current date and after day X. Mybe this is the right way. +1 to your comment for now.

Comment: Will the new database be used (other than for migration) before the go-live date?

Comment: @Dan: the target database will be used for final tests the days just before go live date, but for nothing else before. Therefore other than migration it will not be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a staging table in which tracking migrated docs, for example:

Migration Table

```
--------------------------------------------------
| MigratedDocId | MigrationTimeStamp    |  Other |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1             | anydate               |  blah  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2             | anyotherdate          |  blah  |
```

Assuming you have a Document ID (or any other PK), here's the Main table

```
--------------------------------------
| DocID    | Status  |  CreationDate |
--------------------------------------
| 1        | closed  |  2011         | (migrated according to [2])
--------------------------------------
| 2        | closed  |  2012         | (migrated according to [2])
--------------------------------------
| 3        | open    |  2011         | (*)
--------------------------------------
| 4        | any     |  2009         | (migrated according to [1])
--------------------------------------
```

Now, assume (*) row changes from open to closed, you need to migrate this row to your destination DB checking in your migration at first:

```
    SELECT * FROM MAINTABLE
    WHERE STATUS = 'closed'
    AND M.DOCID NOT IN ( SELECT MIGRATEDDOCID FROM MIGRATIONTABLE )
```

You can improve your query in any way, maybe with a JOIN or with an EXCEPT (I prefer the second one), but here's the simplest way to get only the (*) row. Then after your migration insert DocID into Migration Table. This is one of the principles of **staging area** and sometimes (but this is not the case) you'll need a dedicated DB to store all this kind of support tables and views.

Comment: it is a good approach. It will require some extra components in SSIS (to save the same IDs on the stage tables), but at least it simplifies the process to verify already exported records. +1 for the moment, waiting for other answers before accepting yours. Thanks.

Comment: @Luca thanks, remember to flag as accepted when you've finished to evaluate :) Ciao